# select from multiple table with MAX and SUM

Tags: mysql

I need to query the MySql DB for customer data.

I have customer table, order, and connection table.

I need to find the last visit - MAX( connection.date_add)

and also the SUM of orders.

I tire to do it in one query -

```
select MAX( connection.date_add), SUM(order.total_paid)
from customer 
join order on customer.id = order.c_id
join connection on customer.id = connection.c_id
```

The problem is that the result has 1 line for each connection and the number of orders is multiplied by the number of connection

I solved it by doing 3 queries and than merge the result "manually"

My question: is it possible to do it in one query??

I know that in other SQL dbs you can use the WITH statement, but is there a simple way to do it in MySql, in one query?

---

Cannot add an answer - so here is the solution -

```
SELECT c.id_customer, 
COUNT(DISTINCT  o.id_order ) AS '# VALID ORDERS', 
MAX( co.`date_add` ) AS last_visit,
SUM( o.total_paid )*COUNT(DISTINCT  o.id_order )/COUNT(co.`date_add` ) AS '$ (TOTAL AMOUNT)'
FROM ps_customer AS c
JOIN ps_orders o ON ( c.id_customer = o.id_customer ) 
JOIN ps_connections co ON co.id_customer = g.id_customer 
group by c.id_customer
```

The solution with inner sub-query also works but is way too slow.

Stackoverflow - this is not a duplicate, please read carefully.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Do you want one row per customer or one row overall?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use subqueries *before* the `join`:

```
select MAX(co.date_add), o.total_paid
from customer cu join
     (select c_id, sum(o.total_paid) as total_paid
      from order o
      group by c_id
     ) o
     on cu.id = o.c_id join
     connection co
     on cu.id = co.c_id
```

I am guessing that you also want a `group by cu.id` so you get one row per customer.

I would, in fact, pre-aggregate both tables:

```
select co.maxda, o.total_paid
from customer cu join
     (select c_id, sum(o.total_paid) as total_paid
      from order o
      group by c_id
     ) o
     on cu.id = o.c_id join
     (select co.c_id, max(co.date_add) as maxda
      from connection co
      group by co.c_id
     ) co
     on cu.id = co.c_id
group by cu.id;
```

Comment: Good answer but query is too slow